# Difference between binding and directive

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's take the following example. There are two ways add class to an element:

Class binding

```
<div [class]="currentClasses">Hello world #1</div>
```

Class directive

```
<div [ngClass]="settings">Hello world #1</div>
```

What's the difference in terms of underlying functionality between class binding and class directive? Originally I thought that bindings just write to properties on some object, however there is no such property `class` on HTMLElement, it's `className`, so this reasoning is probably wrong. And it certainly not just adds a `class` attribute to DOM element, because the same syntax is used to bind values to component class fields.

These are the questions that popup in my head as well: Can I implement custom bindings? What mechanism is used behind `[]` binding?

I certainly understand that `ngClass` has sophisticated functionality, like tracking properties on component class, while `class` binding simply adds classes. But this question is not about application, it's about how they are implemented internally.

Comment: How do you add a class in normal html :)? `<div class="currentClass">`. You can bind on properties of elements which you would normally write in `html` as well.

Comment: `[class]` directly adds `class`attribute to resulting html, which is used by browser to get class property of DOM node; `[ngClass]` does same in indirect way; all of it has nothing to do with className - it's javascript property

Comment: @setec, so why this `<div [someattr]="currentClasses">Hello world #1</div>` throws an error and not simply adds `someattr` attribute to `html`?

Comment: Because `[someattr]="currentClasses"` binds the value of the `currentClasses` property of your component class to the `someattr` **property** of the current element. But because one can not set arbitrary properties (in contrary to attributes) you get an error. What you mean is probably `<div [attr.someattr]="currentClasses">` or `<div someattr="currentClasses">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[class.xxx]`, `[attr.xxx]`, `[style.xxx]` is special Angular2 template syntax and processed by Angular2 directly.
This is not extensible and there is only what Angular supports.

On the other side, `[ngClass]` is a directive like you can build it yourself. It's just included in Angular2 by default.

Comment: thanks, so are these three implemented internally with different mechanism than general binding syntax `[propertyOnComponentClass]="value or propertyOnParentComponentClass"`? Do you know what internal class implements these bindings?

Comment: I don't know what class implements it. There is a template parser and based on that there will be some code generated, but I don't know where exactly related code is.

Comment: what about the first part of the question in comment? did you have a chance to debug\explore internals of angular2?

Comment: You mean this part "so are these three implemented internally with different mechanism than general binding syntax ". Yes, this is special binding syntax. No, I didn't debug it. I just saw related commits ocassionally.